# UK standard visitor visa: “The earliest you can apply is 3 months before you travel” meaning?

Tags: uk, standard-visitor-visas, applications

I am asking about this vague statement that is mentioned on the website of UK.GOV.

> The earliest you can apply is 3 months before you travel. ([source](https://www.gov.uk/standard-visitor-visa))

It says you can apply three months from your travel date. If I intend to travel to the UK on the 1st of March, can I apply for my visa in January?

Do they mean that you can apply in the three months that are preceding your travel date and you can’t apply earlier **or** do they mean that you can only apply for a visa before three months of your travel date and no later?

Comment: can you share a link to the statement ?

Comment: https://www.gov.uk/standard-visitor-visa

Comment: It says *”the earliest you can apply is 3 months before you travel”*. Nothing vague about it.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The language is not vague because "three months before your travel date" is the **earliest** you can apply. For example, if you plan to travel on April 1, the earliest day to apply is three months before, or January 1. You may apply any time **after** that three-months-before date.

Comment: Though of course you should provide enough time for the whole process, which can take a little while in some circumstances, especially these days. So probably at the latest 1 month before to be safe, which gives a 2-month window.

Answer (score 1):

I would consider 3 months as 90 days as this is typically how the Home Office/UKVI count things. In your case that would mean you could apply from the 1st of December.

I would also add that this 3 month rule is VERY loosely enforced. They are more flexible on this since Covid given the difficulties in actually being able to book flights, quarantine etc.

Comment: How do you know this rule is "very loosely enforced" ?

Comment: @bon_vivant how sure are you that it is very loosely enforced? I ask since I have applied for UK visa more than 3 months in advance. VFS did accept my application and said this is not a ground for rejection but still seeking confirmation.